# How run java script while ios until "DONE" - IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

How run java script while ios until "DONE"

```
UIViewController *webViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIWebView *uiWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];
[uiWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlToken]]];

NSString *javaScript=[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"BOJavaScript" ofType:@"js"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[uiWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript];
```

Comment: What do you mean "while ios until "DONE"" ?

Comment: While webview execute javascript = DONE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In file MainViewController.h

```
@interface MainViewController :<UIWebViewDelegate>
```

In file MainViewController.m

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSString *javaScript=[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"BOJavaScript" ofType:@"js"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [uiWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` runs on main thread (the `UIWebView` is a UI element) and it returns a `NSString`. No need to "wait" for a response.

Comment: My JavaScript hide element webview.